# Heroku db:push problems

Tags: heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to push my local Postgres db to my Heroku app, and following Heroku guide, I did `heroku db:push` but I get the following error:

```
leonsas@leonsas-VirtualBox:~$ heroku db:push
 !    Taps Load Error: cannot load such file -- sqlite3
 !    You may need to install or update the taps gem to use db commands.
 !    On most systems this will be:
 !    
 !    sudo gem install taps
```

I already tried `sudo gem install taps`, `sudo gem install sqlite3`, but I cant make it work. Any ideas why it's trying to load an sqlite3 db when I'm using postgres?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taps is no longer the recommended tool to use when migrating data between postgres instances. Please give [heroku-pg-transfer](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer) a try instead.

This will only work if you're using one of the [production databases](https://postgres.heroku.com/pricing) or the new [Heroku postgres dev plan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-dev-plan). If you're still on the older shared database plan I would suggest switching to the new dev plan.

First, find the URL to your db on Heroku:

```
$ heroku config:get DATABASE_URL
postgres://yada:yada@ec2-107-21-122-141.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/123
```

Then transfer from your local db to the heroku db:

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-pg-transfer
$ heroku pg:transfer -f postgres://localhost/dbname -t postgres://yada:yada@ec2.../123
```

Since the heroku-pg-transfer tool utilizes postgres's native pg_dump facility it is a much more predictable and resilient tool.

Comment: It seems this is going to work, but It fails to connect to heroku's db.: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] connection to database "hdciwacofe" failed: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
 Is the server running on host "ec2-107-22-235-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (107.22.235.197) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
pg_restore: *** aborted because of error

Comment: Do ou know what database you're using? If you see SHARED_DATABASE_URL when running 'heroku config' then you do and this won't work. You'll have to migrate to a Heroku Dev plan.

Comment: This worked, but it's not very zen. It would be nice if the command was shortened or 'db:push' fixed.