# heroku db:push not working, is there something else I can use

Tags: heroku, sqlite, taps

I have a rails app that runs sqlite locally. I've tried pretty much everything that's recommend in order to fix the dreaded `Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range:` error. I've tried setting different versions of ruby, uninstall and re-install taps gem and sqlite3 and all that stuff.

I'd like to find an different solution. I think what may be nice is if there is a rake task of some kind I could use to maybe export the sqlite and then another rake task that I could run on heroku that would look for the sqlite dump and set up my postgres db with the same data and what not. Is this a possible solution or could anyone recommend a better way ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku db:push problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126652/heroku-dbpush-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sqlite3 locally and Postgres remotely. Please see my other answer here for migrating to postgres locally, which also has a link to Heroku docs on using pgbackups to import/export data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15373024/95741